# How to run code before MainWindow shows up?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I've got a WPF app and want to run code that will edit MainWindow's Resource Dictionnaries before it calls the MainWindow's constructor, but don't know how to do it.
The code can't be located in the MainWindow's constructor as it will result to close and open it recursively (the resource dictionnary change closes and opens the window to make changes visible).

To say it all, I've got a function that pops up a custom (with custom ResourceDictionnaries, I've got several and it switch between them each time the function is called) MainWindow whenever I click a button, but calling it from MainWindow constructor would simply imply a recursion problem.

Can someone help me ? Thanks ! :)

Edit - Thanks for the answer, it works. I made my question as clear as possible now.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is probably to add a startup handler declaration in App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="YourApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:whatever"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" Startup="Application_Startup">
</Application>
```

and then in app.xaml.cs

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // do whatever
    }
```